# Puzzled at the print sequence in nesting print usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have some problem with Python 3's default print sequence in nesting a print function, which can be simplified as the following example:

```py
>>> def print2():
...     print('print2')
... 
>>> print('print1', print2())
print2
print1 None
```

But using the equivalent in Python 2:

```py
>>> def print2():
...     print 'print2'
... 
>>> print 'print1', print2()
print1 print2
None
```

Why is the print sequence reversed？ **And how can I yield the natural sequence in Python 3 (same as in Python 2), not reversed**?

Comment: Why are you printing instead of returning a String? The arguments to a functions are evaluated before the function is, so this is the expected and correct behaviour.

Comment: What you are **probably** instead doing, is use `print 'print1', print2()` in Python2, note the lack of parentheses. And the difference is that `print` is a statement in Python 2, which treats each component separately.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters thanks for your correct, you got it! So how can I get the natural sequence result in Python3?

Comment: @Huan Again, printing inside of a call to print is kind of odd. Instead of trying to change the order, it would be better to not abuse print and instead pass data around and print it when needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference lies in the fact that in Python 2, `print` is a **statement**. It is special in that multiple expressions are evaluated from left to right, and their result is written out immediately.

From the [`print` reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print):

> `print` evaluates each expression in turn and writes the resulting object to standard output

So in Python 2, the statement `print 'print1', print2()` first evaluates `'print1'`, writes that out, then evaluates `print2()`, which itself uses `print` to write out `'print2'`, then writes a newline at the end. The Python interactive interpreter then echoes the return value of the last expression, which was `None`.

In Python 3, `print()` is a [built-in **function**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). Functions are just more expressions. You can't execute a function until all argument expressions have been evaluated. This means that `print(...)` is not actually executed until all it's arguments have been evaluated, and so can't write anything out to your screen until the `print2()` function is done and has returned it's value.

So for `print('print1', print2())` to work, Python first has to evaluate `'print1'` (produces a string object), then evaluate `print2()` (calls `print('print2')` and returns `None`), before the function can be executed and write out `print1 None`.

You would get the same results in Python 2 if you used `print('print1', print2())`, because then you'd actually first create a *tuple* with two elements and that's then printed; `print` is still a statement, and `('print1', print2())` is evualuated to `('print1', None)` (and `print2` written to the screen), before that tuple is converted to a string and written out. Or you can use [`from __future__ import print_function` in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future), at which point the compiler disables the `print` statement and you get to use the `print()` function in Python 2 as well.

The solution is to use two **separate** `print()` function calls, and replace the newline normally written, with a space:

```
print('print1', end=' ')
print(print2())
```

This way, `'print1'` has been written out to your screen before `print2()` has to be called. The above would output

```
print1 print2
None
```

but in an interactive interpreter the lack of newline would muck out the output a little:

```
>>> print('print1', end=' ')
print1 >>> print(print2())
print2
None
```

But you really would not *want* to use `print()` to write out the return value of `print2()`, which is `None` there. Dropping the extra `print()` would leave that out:

```
print('print1', end=' ')
print2()
```

If `print2()` is responsible for printing, don't then double up the printing calls.

The **best** option, however, is to **not print inside `print2()`**. Keep your printing central, and ordering doesn't matter that much any more. Have your functions return a string to be printed, instead:

```
def result2():
    return 'print2'

print('print1', result2())
```

The above would output `print1 print2` in both Python 2 (provided you use the `print` statement, so `print 'print1', result2()`), and in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but return statement will end the nesting……I've posted my real code, take a look!

Comment: @Huan: there is no need to do that; your question was fine without it. I gave some advice on how I'd structure code, you don't need to follow it in detail.

Comment: @Huan: the trick is to *not use print*, but to collect the things you need to print into a list or similar structure. At the end, join the list into a single string, return that, then print.

Comment: @Huan: for that example, my advice still stands, see https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/77e635326d2c9957faefc0dc6277b81f

Comment: Thanks for your solution, what a rookie I am! That's to say, there is no way to use the print function directly in this code, as the print sequence is always reversed in Python 3?

Comment: Nope. You could use the `print(part1, end=' ')`, then `print(part2())` to handle ordering, of course, but that’s just not a good option here because your recursive function calls are mixing printing and returning values to print. You end up printing a lot of extra `None` values. That’s a problem with how this code is designed, not with `print()`, really.